# Stack Overflow says my post has a code formatting problems - how can I locate these?

Tags: support, code-formatting

This is the first time I've tried to ask a question on SO but it won't let me saying

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.

There's code in my post, but I've made sure each line begins with 4 spaces. Also anything elsewhere in camel case I've put in backquotes, but it still won't let me post.

How do I find what the problem is?

The question text is here: http://ubuntuone.com/5uXmcGlxexOWe8UxtLG3CV

Comment: Please post the contents of your question here so we can look at it - [edit] this question to do that.

Comment: You have format your `Coding`.

**[Please refer the Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)**

Comment: Could you please show us the content of the question you were trying to submit? Just copy the markdown to any place where we can see it. Otherwise there is not much to answer here.

Comment: Does the preview look correct? You should have an emty line beofre/after each code block. And does the question contain anything but code?

Comment: The question text is here: http://ubuntuone.com/5uXmcGlxexOWe8UxtLG3CV

Comment: My analysis: I think the system objects to the code-to-text ratio. Remove some code, or add more explanation.

Comment: @michaelb958 there seems to be more than enough text so that this metric shouldn't be triggered

Comment: @JanDvorak 'Twas really a bit of a guess - I can't see any other glaring issues.

Comment: I just put it into the sandbox mentioned here, and it goes in fine. I tried again to ask it in SO and still the same error comes up

Comment: @toby1kenobi that's because the quality filters are all turned off on Meta.